# How can I decode function call argument?

Tags: nearprotocol

I got a function call below as result of calling `txStatus` in `near-api-js`. How can I decode function call argument to plain JSON same as in NEAR explorer?

```js
{
    FunctionCall: {
      method_name: 'withdraw_reward',
      args: 'eyJ0b2tlbl9pZCI6InNuYWlsY29pbi5zbmFpbHNfZmkudGVzdG5ldCIsImFtb3VudCI6IjY2ODM2OTk4NDcxMiIsInVucmVnaXN0ZXIiOmZhbHNlfQ==',
      gas: 100000000000000,
      deposit: '1'
    }
  }
```

See on [explorer](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/HeiuYeHkovf4nZwmc5evSuwP91UtktZ4jGYJY3gHrD2N):

```json
{
  "token_id": "snailcoin.snails_fi.testnet",
  "amount": "668369984712",
  "unregister": false
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's base64

using https://www.base64decode.org I see

```
{"token_id":"snailcoin.snails_fi.testnet","amount":"668369984712","unregister":false}
```

for sure you would do this using a library or something, maybe this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64

Comment: Thank you, so luckily I don't need any special decoding function i.e. in Ethereum